# iOS mapView - drag pin with only one tap

Tags: ios, mkmapview, draggable

I have a MapView with two pins on it (custom pins).

Both pins are set to draggable, but my problem is before I can drag one of them I first have to select it before I can start dragging it. This means two taps on the screen.

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068637/how-can-drag-mkpinannotationview-pin-only-one-tap) answer, but he only has one pin ons his map and it seems to me only one pin at a time can be selected so setting the [MyPin setSelected:YES]; wouldn't help me in this case.

Thanks for the help!

```
//Custom pin on mapview
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

            MKAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];

             MyPin.draggable = YES;

            //Get annotaion title to determine what image to use
            MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
            annotationPoint = annotation;

            if([annotationPoint.title isEqualToString:@"user"])
            {
                MyPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userLocation_pin"];
                MyPin.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-13, -5); //Offset custom image to display at the exact pin point GPointMake([left/right], [up/down]);
            }
            else if ([annotationPoint.title isEqualToString:@"destination"])
            {
                MyPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"destination_pin_up"];
                MyPin.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-13, -5); //Offset custom image to display at the exact pin point GPointMake([left/right], [up/down]);
            }

            return MyPin;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve my own problem by adding the [MyPin setSelected:YES]; inside the if statements like this:

```
//Custom pin on mapview
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

            MKAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];

             MyPin.draggable = YES;

            //Get annotaion title to determine what image to use
            MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
            annotationPoint = annotation;

            if([annotationPoint.title isEqualToString:@"user"])
            {
                MyPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userLocation_pin"];
                MyPin.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-13, -5); //Offset custom image to display at the exact pin point GPointMake([left/right], [up/down]);
                [MyPin setSelected:YES];
            }
            else if ([annotationPoint.title isEqualToString:@"destination"])
            {
                MyPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"destination_pin_up"];
                MyPin.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-13, -5); //Offset custom image to display at the exact pin point GPointMake([left/right], [up/down]);
                [MyPin setSelected:YES];
            }

            return MyPin;
        }
```